# SPSS - Graph of sums of variables across cases?

Tags: charts, spss

My question is very similar to [Compute sum of all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345941/compute-sum-of-all-cases), but whereas that person only needed to sum a single variable, I'd like to sum a number of variables, and then make a bar chart depicting all the sums of the different variables (i.e. I want to sum not only `pageviews` but also `totalhits`, and then make a two-bar chart which displays the sum).

How would I go about doing that in SPSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is to make a bar chart of the sums, you do not *need* to aggregate the data at all, you can do that directly in `GGRAPH`. See example below.

```
*Fake data.
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 10.
  COMPUTE A = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
  COMPUTE B = RV.NORMAL(2,1).
  END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
DATASET NAME Sim.
FORMATS A B (F2.0).
EXECUTE.

*Summing in GGRAPH directly.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=SUM(A) SUM(B) TRANSFORM=VARSTOCASES(SUMMARY="sum" INDEX="var")
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: sum=col(source(s), name("sum"))
  DATA: var=col(source(s), name("var"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Variables"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Sum"))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(var*sum))
END GPL.
```

[image]

This is similar to using `VARSTOCASES`, but just directly in `GGRAPH` without having to change your data to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the sum of a few variables all you need to do is add them to the `aggregate` command.

Using @AndyW's example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345941/compute-sum-of-all-cases):

```
data list free /browser (A2) pageviews (F6.0)  month (A3) year (A4) totalhits (F6.0) percentage (F4.2).
begin data
ch     227025   Nov 2012    626760      36.22
ie     184232   Nov 2012    626760      29.39
s       81430   Nov 2012    626760      12.99
ff      72140   Nov 2012    626760      11.51
ie      39856   Nov 2012    626760      06.36
o        1010   Nov 2012    626760      00.16
rm        325   Nov 2012    626760      00.05
ot      20742   Nov 2012    626760      03.31
end data.

compute const = 1.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=*
  MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=const
  /pageviews_sum totalhits_sum = SUM(pageviews totalhits).
```

Now this will add the total sums to the active dataset.
For your chart you may want just the sums in a separate dataset:

```
DATASET DECLARE sums.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE='sums'
  /BREAK=const
  /pageviews_sum totalhits_sum = SUM(pageviews totalhits).
dataset activate sums.
```

Once you have the sums just use Graphs > chart builder to create your preferred chart.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to make the chart once I've aggregated my data, that alone isn't the issue :)

Comment: I've already accepted Andy's solution, but I'd be interested in hearing how would this be accomplished with your approach

Comment: my best suggestion is you play around with the chary builder wizard, pick the chart format you like best, then paste the syntax so you can repeat this later without going through the wizard again.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to find a way to create a bar chart from multiple variables of a single case, that is my question :)

Comment: Actually the best thing to do would be to open a new question for this, as these are two separate individual problems.